# Implementing Google Smart Home Request Sync

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I am trying to implement Google Smart Home Request Sync. Is it normal, that I have to say sync devices once I change the name of the device? Is there a way to force it without saying so? Here is my code:

```js
exports.adduser = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    app.requestSync(request.body.token).then((res) => {
        firebaseRef.child('devices/' + request.body.token).set([request.body.id,]);
        response.status(200).json({ 'status': 'OK' });
    }).catch((res) => {
        response.status(500).json({ 'status': 'FAILED' });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync):

> You must trigger a SYNC request:
>
> - If the user adds a new device.
> - If the user removes an existing device.
> - **If the user renames an existing device**.
> - **If you implement a new device
>   type, trait, or add a new device feature.**

Without the SYNC request, a mismatch in device state can occur between [Home Graph](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/homegraph) and the device, which can lead to functionality and reliability issues for users.